mocking out imported objects in Python
Lets say there is a module headache that defines an object that is then imported and used by code I want to test:
# defined in headache/__init__.py

problem = Problem()

then it's imported by Foo:
# this is foo.py

from headache import problem

class Foo:
  # uses `problem` object

and by Bar:
# this is bar.py

from headache import problem

class Bar:
  # uses `problem` object

now, when testing I can patch problem, but I must do it for every user of problem independently:
unittest.mock.patch(target="foo.problem", new=...)

and
unittest.mock.patch(target="bar.problem", new=...)

which makes it really hard if I have a lot of problems. Is there a sensible way to patch the problem once, before it's imported by other modules?

Could you use @patch(target=headache.problem, new=mock_problem) before the method setUp() of the test class? The mock object could be saved as an attribute of the test class inside the setUp() method as following: self.mock_problem = mock_problem. You can refer to this post.
